# Android app save data from JSON receieved from a PHP script

Tags: java, php, android

I wanna save some data from a server that send it to my app using a PHP script.
Now, my problem is that I received the data at the app level but i can't save it correctly because I see it as blank "".
I attach my code from the PHP script:

```
        $response2 = array();
        $response= array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2) )
          {
    $response = 

 array("cod_client"=>$row[0],"cnp"=>$row[1],"kilograme"=>$row[2],"inaltime"=>$row[3]);

          }


        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
        {
        $response2 = array("fitness"=>$row2[0]);
        }

        echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));

        echo json_encode(array("values"=>$response2));
```

and here is the Android JAVA app code:

```
     String err=null;
        try
        {

    JSONObject emp=(new JSONObject(result)).getJSONObject("user_data");
      JSONObject emp2 =(new JSONObject(result)).getJSONObject(values");




            cod_client = emp.getString("cod_client");
            cnp = emp.getString("cnp");
            kg=emp.getString("kilograme");
            inaltime=emp.getString("inaltime");


          String fitness=emp2.getString("fitness");
            Toast.makeText(ctx,"values of fitness are: "+fitness,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            Toast.makeText(ctx,"id is "+cod_client+"cnp este "+cnp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } 
catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
```

I receive the value of fitness as "10" but i can't save it on the string fitness.
The first JSON it's working I receive the values and I can save them in the "cod_client", "cnp", "kg" and "inaltime".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you do multiple echo of jsons then it will become invalid json. add it as array in single array
change

```
echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));

echo json_encode(array("values"=>$response2));
```

To

```
echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response,"values"=>$response2));
```